# Terraform unable to modify IAMBetaWorkloadIdentityPool with own service account

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to setup terraform to manage a service account for Github actions. I ran the initial terraform code as my own owner GCP account and I'm transitioning it over to GHA itself using it's own service account.

When the action tries to run plan I get the following (the rest of the plan refreshes fine):

```
Error: Error when reading or editing IAMBetaWorkloadIdentityPool "projects/env-test/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/github-actions": googleapi: Error 403: Permission 'iam.workloadIdentityPools.get' denied on resource '//iam.googleapis.com/projects/env-test/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/github-actions' (or it may not exist).
Details:
[
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
    "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",
    "metadata": {
      "permission": "iam.workloadIdentityPools.get",
      "resource": "projects/spareroom-test/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/github-actions"
    },
    "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
]

  with google_iam_workload_identity_pool.github_actions_wip,
  on wip.tf line 1, in resource "google_iam_workload_identity_pool" "github_actions_wip":
   1: resource "google_iam_workload_identity_pool" "github_actions_wip" {
```

I've seen a reference to needing `roles/iam.workloadIdentityPoolAdmin` beta permission but I'm unsure where to apply it, I tried applying it to the service acccount:

```
resource "google_service_account_iam_binding" "github_service_account_admin" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.github_service_account.name
  role               = "roles/iam.workloadIdentityPoolAdmin"

  members = [
    "principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/${google_iam_workload_identity_pool.github_actions_wip.name}/attribute.repository_owner/Env"
  ]
}
```

but I get:

```
googleapi: Error 400: Role roles/iam.workloadIdentityPoolAdmin is not supported for this resource., badRequest
```

I'm currently unable to get the service account to manage itself and would appreciate any help!

Comment: For your last error, you are trying to add that role to the service account's policy. You are trying to manage the service account as a resource. Instead, add the role to the project's IAM policy. Note: I am not sure what your actual problem is, this is a comment on where to add roles. A service account can be both an identity and a resource, depending on the context.